# concating multiple strings in one line c++

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, stringstream

I tried to overload operator "<<" to get similar behaviour like with std::stringstream.
I want to concate multiple strings in one line and pass them to another function after the last word in the line.

```
struct Log
{
    std::string outString;

    template<typename T>
    friend Log& operator<<(Log& log, const T& t)
    {
        std::stringstream temp;
        temp << t;
        std::string str = temp.str();
        log.outString += str;
        if(str == "endl" || str == "\n")
        {
            //end of line -> pass string to custom print function
        }
        return log;
    }
};
```

i get a segmentation fault in this line:

```
log.outString += str;
```

Should be called like this.

```
log << "blub: " << 123 << "endl";
```

Comment: try to replace `if(t == "endl" || t== "\n")` with `if(str == "endl" || str == "\n")`

Comment: I recommend to use something more robust than strings for `"endl"`, because the compiler has no chance to help you with typos. For example an enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing an integer in the statement `if(t == "endl" || t== "\n")`, replace it with `if(str == "endl" || str == "\n")`.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Logg
{
    std::string outString;

    template<typename T>
    friend Logg& operator<<(Logg& logg, const T& t)
    {
        std::stringstream temp;
        temp << t;
        std::string str = temp.str();
        logg.outString += str;
        if(str == "endl" || str == "\n")
        {
            //end of line -> pass string to custom print function
        }
        return logg;
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct Logg logg;
    logg << "blub: " << 123 << "endl";
    std::cout << logg.outString << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i fixed it. But this has nothing to do with my segfault, when i try to access log.outString.

Comment: you still getting segmentation fault after the correction?

Comment: yes, i think the parameter order is wrong. i cannot access a member variable of this reference parameter.

Comment: not getting any segfault in my code version. Check the updated answer.